# Debugging error -- error attaching to w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, w3wp

I am using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C#. And I developed a custom Forms authentication module for IIS 7.0 and I attach to w3wp.exe to debug this module. During the attach process (I just select Tools -> Attach to Process, no further operation performed on the computer I am debugging -- I just wait for the attach to be completed), I met with the following error, any ideas what is wrong?

The web server process that was being debugged has been terminated by Internet Information Services (IIS). This can be avoided by configuring Application Pool ping settings in IIS. See help for further details.

Comment: My guess would be that you need to configure Application Pool ping settings in IIS.

Answer (score 20):

JUST 1 STEP to fix this:

1. Open the Administrative Tools window.
2. Click Start and then choose Control Panel.
   3.In Control Panel, choose Switch to Classic View, if necessary, and then double-click Administrative Tools.
3. In the Administrative Tools window, double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.image
4. In the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager window, expand the  node.
5. Under the  node, right-click Application Pools.
6. In the Application Pools list, right-click the name of the pool your application runs in, and then click Advanced Settings.
7. In the Advanced Settings dialog box, locate the Process Model section and chose one of the following actions:
        *.Set Ping Enabled to False. 
           —or—
        *.Set Ping Maximum Response Time to a value greater than 90 seconds.

Setting Ping Enabled to False stops IIS from checking whether the worker process is still running and keeps the worker process alive until you stop your debugged process. Setting Ping Maximum Response Time to a large value allows IIS to continue monitoring the worker process.

9.Click OK.

Comment: http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.com/2009/08/web-server-process-that-was-being.html http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763108.aspx